# searched listview item position change when I click on searched item

Tags: android, arrays, xml, listview

Following is my adapter class

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    //private ArrayList<SongModel> songsList = null;
    SongAdapter songAdapter;
    private ArrayList<SongModel> songsListDat = null;
    private ArrayList<SongModel> songsList;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SongAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<SongModel> songsListDat) {

        this.context = activity;
        this.songsListDat = songsListDat;
        this.songsList = new ArrayList<SongModel>();
        this.songsList.addAll(songsListDat);

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songsListDat.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return songsListDat.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songTitle); // title
        SongModel song = new SongModel();
        song = songsListDat.get(position);
        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.getSongTitle());

        return vi;
    }


    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        songsListDat.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            songsListDat.addAll(songsList);
        }
        else {
            for (SongModel song : songsList) {
                if (song.getSongPath().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    songsListDat.add(song);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Following is my main activity class fragment

```
EditText edtSearch;
ListAdapter adapter;
SongAdapter songAdapter;
ArrayList<SongModel> songList = new ArrayList<SongModel>();
SongsManager songsManager = new SongsManager();

// Songs list
public ArrayList<SongModel> songsList = new ArrayList<>();
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View windows = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist, container, false);
     return windows;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

    edtSearch = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.search);
    final ArrayList<SongModel> songsListData = songsManager.songList;
    Log.i("songsListData...",""+songsListData.size());
    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();

    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < songsListData.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        SongModel song = songsListData.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
    }
    // Adding menuItems to ListView
   /* adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), songsListData, R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
            R.id.songTitle });*/

    songAdapter = new SongAdapter(getActivity(),songsList);
    setListAdapter(songAdapter);
    // selecting single ListView item
    final ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single listitem click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg0,
                                int position, long id) {

            // getting listitem index
            Log.i("Index", "..." + position);
            //int songIndex = position;
            // Starting new intent
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
            songAdapter.getItem(position);
            // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
            i.putExtra("songIndex",position);
            getActivity().setResult(100, i);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }
    });
    edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = edtSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            songAdapter.filter(text);
        }
    });
}}
```

This is my model class

public class SongModel {

```
private String songPath;
private String songTitle;
public SongModel(String songPath,String songTitle)
{
    this.songPath  = songPath;
    this.songTitle  = songTitle;
}
public void setSongPath(String songPath){
    this.songPath = songPath;
}
public String getSongPath() {
    return songPath;
}
public void setSongTitle(String songTitle){
    this.songTitle = songTitle;
}
public String getSongTitle() {
    return songTitle;
}}
```

How i get the exact position of searched listview item position.
If any one know help me.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: as per your question, the problem is if original id of song is 5 and after search it becomes 1 and on click you get 1, but you want 5, am I correct ?

Comment: yes, I face this problem when i click on searched item and get wrong position.

Comment: can u share the SongModel class?

Comment: sort  ArrayList<SongModel> songsListDat by alphabetical and then set adapter can solve your problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg0,
                            int position, long id) {

        // getting listitem index
        Log.i("Index", "..." + position);
        //int songIndex = position;
        // Starting new intent
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Main.class);
        SongModel song = (SongModel)songAdapter.getItem(position);
        // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
        i.putExtra("songIndex",song.getId() );
        getActivity().setResult(100, i);
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    }
});
```

see you must have a unique id for song in your song model, pass that id instead.
hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The original indexes of items is lost when `filter()` and `notifyDatasetChanged()` are called. In order to retrieve the original positions, do this in `onItemClick()`:

```
SongModel sm = songAdapter.getItem(position);
int originalIndex = songAdapter.songList.indexOf(sm);
//Do whatever you want with originalIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

I got simple answer for you. In your `onItemClick()` where you perform `songAdapter.getItem(position);`, do something as follows:

```
int actualPostion=songsList.indexOf(songAdapter.getItem(position));
```

This will be the actual position in your original list of selected song.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code given below change it accordingly

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToursModel> {

    private List<SongModel> originalList;
    private List<SongModel> tourList;
    private SongFilter filter;
    private Context context;

    public SongAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SongModel> songList) {
        super(context, resource, songList);
        this.context = context;
        this.songList = new ArrayList<SongModel>();
        this.songList.addAll(tourList);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.originalList.addAll(songList);
//        backup = songList;
        getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new TourFilter();
        }
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        // Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.tour_list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView songName;
    }

    private class TourFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<SongModel> filteredItems = new ArrayList<SongModel>();

                for (int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++) {
                    SongModel country = originalList.get(i);
                    if (country.getTourDes().toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                        filteredItems.add(country);
                }
                result.count = filteredItems.size();
                result.values = filteredItems;
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    result.values = originalList;
                    result.count = originalList.size();
                    // Log.e("originalist", "" + originalList.size());
                }
//               // Log.e("originalist", "original");
            }
            return result;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            tourList = (ArrayList<SongModel>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
            clear();
            for (int i = 0, l = songList.size(); i < l; i++)
                add(tourList.get(i));
//                notifyDataSetInvalidated();

        }
    }
}
```